# Will my Observable using shareReplay() run forever, even without active subscribers?

Tags: rxjs, observable

Consider this **Observable**:

```
myObs$ = interval(1000).pipe(shareReplay(2));
```

And its usage:

```
myObs$.subscribe(res => console.log('[Subscriber 1]:' + res));
```

If I subscribe, then unsubscribe a few seconds later, and finally resubscribe again after another few seconds, **it seems like the interval kept running and counting**:

```
[Subscriber 1]: 0
[Subscriber 1]: 1 
Unsubscribe, resubscribe here
[Subscriber 1]: 3
[Subscriber 1]: 4
[Subscriber 1]: 5
[Subscriber 1]: 6 
Unsubscribe, resubscribe here
[Subscriber 1]: 10
[Subscriber 1]: 11
[Subscriber 1]: 12
```

I understood that this does not happen when using refCount = true. **But when it is false, does this count as a potential memory leak ?** If not, how do I stop it?

Also, **why do I need to recreate my Subscription after unsubscribing?**

```
sub = new Subscription()
sub.add(myObs.subscribe())
sub.unsubscribe()
sub.add(myObs.subscribe()) // <-- this does not work unless I recreate a new Subscription()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `shareReply` without `refCount` can result in a memory leak because the operator doesn't close automatically the stream after everyone has unsubscribed. You can make a long lived stream complete by using the [takeUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil) operator which accepts another stream and it's very useful when used with a `Subject`.

```js
const sub = new Subject();

const stream$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  takeUntil(sub),
  shareReplay(1)
);

setTimeout(() => stream$.subscribe(console.log), 4000);
setTimeout(() => sub.next(), 6000);
setTimeout(() => stream$.subscribe(undefined, undefined, () => console.log('completed')), 8000); // this will log completed because the stream$ has successfully finished
```

Another way to complete a stream is with [takeWhile](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takewhile) which is very handy as well and it uses a predicate function.

If you dispose a subscription it is marked as closed and you need to create a new one, it cannot be reused again.

Take a look on [this line](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/e5402fc1204a6f861645310a9d24f9458b288427/src/internal/Subscription.ts#L122) where inside the add method there is a check and if closed is true just executes the teardown on the provided subscription.